# Adding gdbm on Debian (Beagle Bone Black)

Tags: debian, gcc, gdbm

So right now I'm going through my An Introduction to GCC book and I'm up to chapter 3 with gdbm. Now it wasn't there in the first place, and I've tried some "gdbm" "gdbm-devel" to get C gdbm on debian. The Beaglebone build of debian doesn't have it as default. I've looked through the repository and I'm struggling to find non-python related gdbm. What's the package manager command/how and where to build and install gdbm on debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [libgdbm-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libgdbm-dev):

```
# apt-get install libgdbm-dev
```

In general, you can search for a package like this:

```
$ apt-cache search gdbm-dev
```

Or if you know a filename that should be included in the package you could search for that:

```
$ apt-file update
$ apt-file search filename
```

Other times, if you know a package that must somehow depend on the searched package - then you can follow that dependencies, e.g. also via e.g. `apt-cache` or http://packages.debian.org.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly, and because of you I was able to find the boost library too!